# Measuring time spent in each layer in Visual Studio Load Tests

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, performance-testing

I want to measure the time spent in each layer or module in my application.

[Dynatrace](http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/application-monitoring.html) has such a feature. I wonder if this is possible with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate's own load testing tool?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to profile .Net application using Visual Studio Profiler. For asp.net, you can enable profiling by editing test settings file as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504817.aspx).

However, the will only use the Sampling Method : it's a statistical profiling method that shows you the functions that are doing most of the user mode work in the application. You don't have timings, but it's a good place to start to look for areas to speed up your application. You can also get tiers interactions (WCF or ADO.net).

You can also profile an application using your favorite profiler during a load test because VS load testing tool can run setup/cleanup code.

**Edit :**
As I said, all is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426235.aspx).

Create new /update current test settings file. Be Sure to select it before the run (Test/Test Settings/Select).

Be sure to check "ASP.NET Profiler" in the settings.

[image]

Run load tests as usual. At the end you will see a new icon in the tests results.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain it in more detail how to profile an application during a load test?